# Ruby: Change class based on array value

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I'm looking to create an HTML structure with classes based on the values of arrays from Ruby.
I have 6 classes that will be applied to different elements on an 8x8 grid.
Each row will be a div with 8 span elements inside. In ruby, each nested array will be the div row and then each element will be a span assigned a class based on the value of the array element.

```
a = [[1,4,3,2,2,3,1,4]
     [4,5,6,6,3,2,3,5]]
```

So two rows will be created with 8 elements inside with the appropriate classes.
Is it possible to convert data structures to HTML like this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
a = [[1,4,3,2,2,3,1,4],
     [4,5,6,6,3,2,3,5]]

html = ''
a.each do |row|
  html << "<div>%s</div>" % row.map { |c| %{<span class="#{c}"></span>} }.join
end

# puts html
```

**update**

In other words:

```
html = a.map do |row|
  "<div>%s</div>" % row.map { |c| %{<span class="#{c}"></span>} }.join
end.join
```

Answer (score 0):

umm.. yea. something among the lines of...

```
a.each do |subArray|
  puts "<div>"
  subArray.each do |element|
    puts '<span class="#{element}">Some text</span>'
  end
  puts "</div>
end
```

If this doesn't fit your needs please post a more specific question.

Comment: `puts` to produce HTML? Really?